# Formatting C: (windows 7) on an already partitioned hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting

I'm thinking about formatting my hard drive which is running windows 7. I partitioned it a while ago so I could dual boot with windows 8, so basically right now my drive is separated for use with both OSes.

For now I'd like to keep the windows 8 from before to have a running operating system at my disposal in case things go wrong.

What I want to do is wipe windows 7 completely and do a fresh install of windows 8, but I'm not sure if I need another license to be running a second windows 8 on the same computer.

Is this possible? How do I go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provided its the same computer you can partition your hdd as many times as you want and install Windows 8 on all those partitions.  Just install Windows 8 on the partition that has Windows 7 on it.

Comment: If I replace windows 7 with windows 8, will I be able to use windows 7 again? Or does it get completely overridden?

Comment: **You specifically say you want to get rid of it.**  If you don't want to wipe the Windows 7 parition then install Windows 8 on a different partition or simply use the `Reset` feature within your current Windows 8 installation ( would give you the same result ).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm a bit of a n00b. By "wiping windows completely" I meant getting rid of the data, not necessarily erasing every trace of w7. What I'm asking is, if I needed to install 7 somewhere else for any reason, would that be possible (since I have my license key and all)?

Comment: If you are using a Windows 8 Upgrade License its not possible.  If you are using a Windows 8 System Builder license its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a. Computer. In this agreement, “computer” means a hardware system (whether physical or virtual) with an internal storage device capable of running the software. A hardware partition or blade is considered to be a computer. The software is licensed to run on only one processor on the licensed 
>   computer.

based on the top of page 3 of the [Windows 8 license agreement](http://download.microsoft.com/Documents/UseTerms/Windows_8_English_ca383862-45cf-467e-97d3-386e0e0260a6.pdf), you would not be allowed to use the same license twice even if it is on the same physical machine. you would have to buy another license.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you do not disable/format the first Windows 8 installation, then yes you need to purchase a new license to install it again. You have two active installations, you need two licenses. (Same as how you need a separate license if you run Windows 8 inside of a virtual machine)

You would go about doing this by formatting (erasing) the Windows 7 partition and installing Windows 8 on the now-empty partition. It should automatically detect the other Windows 8 installation and add it to the bootloader for you (if not, you can add it manually later).

Comment: I don't agree he will need two licenses.  Its the same computer and hdd.  Unlike a virtual machine both installations cannot be used at the sametime.  Of course I am willing to accept the difference between actual license and my percieved reality of things.  I just view a situation like this for face value, only one installation will be used, the other likely will be wiped once the new one is working.